# Larger multiplexers?

Tags: components, multiplexer

I ordered a few of [these](http://uk.farnell.com/nxp/74hc1g66gw-125/analog-switch-ic-single-spst-tssop/dp/1867069)! , turns out they are a lot smaller then I planned (they are the size of a small ant). I was wondering if anyone knew where,if, I can find larger, preferably dime sized prototyping multiplexers? Or some piece of equipment that does a similar job.

Comment: The title is not very descriptive.  Usually the phrase "large multiplexer" would refer to a multiplexer with a large number of inputs (e.g. 32 or so), or perhaps a parallel multiplexer with many outputs (e.g. one which selects one of two 32-bit words).

Comment: You might want to familiarize yourself with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/THT vs http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface-mount_technology . That way you should be able to order parts that are right size :)

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for through hole multiplexers, then something like the [4051](http://uk.farnell.com/texas-instruments/cd74hct4051e/ic-logic-analog-mux-demux-16dip/dp/1740172), [4052](http://uk.farnell.com/texas-instruments/sn74lv4052an/logic-dual-4-ch-mux-demux-16dip/dp/1750472) or [4053](http://uk.farnell.com/texas-instruments/sn74lv4053an/logic-trip-2-ch-mux-demux-16dip/dp/1750473) are very common and cheap.

The part shown is quite usable for hand soldering though.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have those, I would recommend investing in a Schmart board: http://www.schmartboard.com/index.asp?page=products_so  Just match up the pitch of your part with one of the SOIC boards that Schmart offers.  You could probably fit a few of your muxes on one board and just run off the wires to your application.